# How to inline Bootstrap 3 progress bars?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to be able to put some inline element right next to a `Bootstrap 3` progress bar like following:

```
Some inline element [progress bar]
Some inline element [progress bar]
Some inline element [progress bar]
```

I've tried the following with no luck:

- Adding `display: inline` - bar not showing
- Adding `float: right` - bar not showing
- Using tables to achieve the layout - bar not showing inside `<td>`

Here's the bootply with my attemps: http://www.bootply.com/9jNcnGRkUK

Comment: What about float left for some inline element?

Comment: Just make your own progress bar. Even floating one to the left and the other to the right somehow they still appeared one above the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can apply the [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) as following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <h3>inline</h3>
    <span class="col-sm-3">Some inline element</span>
    <div class="progress" class="col-sm-9">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 45%">
        <span class="sr-only">45% Complete</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

[Try it your self](http://www.bootply.com/Ch8aadiq1x). Note that the  `col-sm-*` class should be put within the `row` class.

Comment: Oh god, it was so simple. I don't know why I haven't even tried the grid system, which is the bootstrap way.

Answer (score 3):

Why `inline`? I've tried `inline-block` with a specified `width` and it works fine: http://www.bootply.com/LsNz4F87Np

Comment: Awesome! I needed to display multiple progress bars inline on the same line.